# Selenium - Upload a file located in a cloud folder

Tags: selenium

I am trying to upload a set of files in some of my Selenium scripts which will be used as a pipeline in a deployment process.
However the sendKeys approach only works for local files, and the files won't always be in the same folder.
Is there a way to have the files in a cloud service (like google drive) and via URL upload them in Selenium scripts?

Comment: Did you try sending the cloud URLs instead local machine file location paths by `sendKeys()` to the appropriate `input` web element on the site where you trying to upload them?

Comment: Add programming language tag

Comment: found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655918/selenium-file-upload-from-url-instead-of-local-file?rq=1) Got any lead on this question?